# How to eliminate gaps in vinyl siding

Tags: siding, vinyl

Has this siding been installed correctly.  Is there any way to close the gaps?[image]

Comment: That looks normal. Vinyl siding contracts and expand a lot as temperatures fluctuate so don’t try to caulk those gaps.

Comment: From this picture we see shadows. Not clear there is any gap. Can you provide a close-up?  Vinyl siding is hung like roofing shingles. This allows for the substantial change in dimensions with temperature. You don’t want to fight that. On the other hand, the bottom of each shingle usually snaps over the next row so there’s not really a gap.

Answer (score 2):

The sliver of a gap between lapped "boards" is normal, and those boards should be left to move with respect to one another. Normally laps are installed such that they have the least visual impact from one particular direction, such as from the front entry.

You've discovered one of the primary drawbacks to vinyl siding. Steel can be had in seamless lengths, but to my knowledge vinyl cannot.